# Pointwise convergence with convergence in measure to some function

Tags: measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

I have the following question about measure theory:

> Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $A$ be a measurable set. We say that $(f_n(x))_n$ convergences in measure $\mu$ to the function $f(x)$ on the set $A$, if the functions $f,f_n$ are measurable, finite a.e. in $A$, and for all $\delta>0$: 
> $ \lim_{k \to \infty} = \mu(\{x\in A : |f_k(x)-f(x)| \ge \delta \})= 0$ 
> Show that if $f_n \to f$ pointwise in $A$, and $(f_n)_n$ converges in measure to some function, than $f_n \to f$ in measure on $A$.

The definition for convergence in measure here is a bit like the local convergence in measure, only here we don't assume that $A$ is of finite measure. 
At first, I tried to use the claim that if $f_n \to g$ in measure then there exists a subsequence that convergences pointwise a.e. to $g$. However, for this proof, I need to use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, which we haven't learned yet. Also, I don't think it's applicable to the definition of converges to measure that we use. 
Perhaps there's a trick here or something obvious that I'm missing, but I could use a hint on this.

Comment: Is the assumption $\mu(A)<\infty$ missing?

Comment: As I've written, it is not assumed that $A$ is of finite measure, but I should ask if it is. Is that assumption important for the question?

Comment: I think it is important for convergence in measure in arbitrary measure spaces. See e.g. Definition 22.2 in Schilling's Measures, Integrals and Martingales.

Comment: I don't have this book, but do you have a counterexample against the set not having a finite measure?

Comment: I've asked my lecturer and she said that it's not assumed that the set is of finite measure.

Comment: @Snoop the assumption that $\mu(A)<\infty $ is not needed here, as we already knows that $f_n$ converges in measure to some (unknown) function